# Replace section of audio in a video with FFmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, encoding, video-encoding

I have a *Recording A* (video and audio) with a length of about 42 minutes.

I also have a separate *Audio Stream B* of the same event, which is identical to the audio in the video except it's a) much better in quality and b) only covers the first 29:34 minutes.

Is it possible to do a direct replacement of the first 29:34 minutes of Recording A's audio with Audio Stream B, while keeping the remaining 12 or so minutes of Recording A's audio in place? In other words, a kind of "overlay" of Audio Stream B on top of Recording A's audio stream.

*Ideally, a solution would completely remove the first 29:34 minutes of Recording A's audio from the file (and therefore the file size), but it would be acceptable even if it just silenced it without decreasing the file size.*

Comment: Show the complete output of `ffmpeg -i a -i b`

Comment: @llogan Unfortunately I've had to abandon this entirely because Audio Stream B is not not perfectly identical - it's a few milliseconds ahead which results in sync problems with the video.

Comment: Related to fixing that problem I have a separate question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1631385/discard-sections-of-audio-with-ffmpeg) if you can spare the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is to extract the original audio out from *Recording A*, clip it so that only the last 12 or so minutes of the audio remains, then merge it with *Audio Stream B*, and finally merge it with the video file again.

### Step 1: Extract Original Audio

To extract the original audio out, you will first need to know the audio format of Recording A, which you should be able to find out by running `ffprobe Recording A`. For the purpose of this example, I'm going to assume that the video file is `.mp4` and the audio is `.ogg`:

```
ffmpeg -i RecordingA.mp4 -vn -acodec copy audio.ogg
```

This should create a new file called `audio.ogg`.

### Step 2: Clip Original Audio

After extracting it out, you will want to clip it so that only the last 12:26 minutes are remaining (assuming that Recording A is exactly 42 minutes long):

```
ffmpeg -ss 1774 -t 2520 -i audio.ogg clipped.ogg
```

This should create a new file called `clipped.ogg`.

### Step 3: Merge with Audio Stream B

Now, you will need to merge the clipped audio with Audio Stream B. To do that, run the following:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:AudioStreamB.ogg|clipped.ogg" -i file2.mp3 -acodec copy final.ogg -map_metadata 0:1
```

This should create a new file called `final.ogg`.

### Final Step: Merge with Video

After you have recompiled your audio, you will need to replace it back with the video. To do so, run the following:

```
ffmpeg -i RecordingA.mp4 -i final.ogg -c:v copy -c:a aac -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 RecordingB.mp4
```

The new file, named `RecordingB.mp4`, should be what you want.

Comment: I was afraid that this would be the only way to do it as I wanted to avoid further encodes, but if it is, I'll test as soon as possible. One clarification: on Step 2 does the `-t 2520` have any advantage if cropping to the end? Wouldn't `ffmpeg -ss 1774 -i audio.ogg clipped.ogg` achieve the same result?

Comment: Yes, I believe ```ffmpeg -ss 1774 -i audio.ogg clipped.ogg``` will do the same.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the "file2.mp3" in step 3 in ffmpeg command ?